# HttpStatus for thrown exceptions isnt handled right in Spring Boot 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just migrated to SpringBoot 3.0.0, but found out, the application fails to handle HttpStatus right, when exception is thrown. It always gives 403 FORBIDDEN (or other code configured for unauthenticated requests). Seems like the authentication is lost after exception is catched or something.
I made a minimalistic example here:

https://gitlab.com/gobanit-public/stack-overflow/spring-boot-3-http-status-bug

There are 4 classes:

**DemoApplication** - application starter

**CustomAuthFilter** - custom authentication filter that sets dummy Authentication to AuthManager.

**Web Config** - web configuration for security. Authentication required for any request.

**Test Controller** - basic controller with three endpoints - one for success and two for failure

When calling the success endpoint, you get the response. The authentication works fine. When the fail endpoint is called, it throws HttpResponseException with HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST (400). However, i dont get 400 in response but 403 instead. That does not seem right. The same happens when the second fail endpoint is called, which doesnt throw exception but writes error response directly.

Is this bug. or am I missing something? I could not find anything related to this in 3.0.0 release notes. It worked fine in 2.7.* versions and even in 3.0.0-RC1, but changed in 3.0.0-RC2 and 3.0.0.

Thanks!

I tried it without Spring Security - it works ok.

I tried it with default basic auth, without custom auth filter - it works fine too.

So I guess it is somehow related to Spring Security filter.

I tried different versions of SpringBoot - 2.7.5 (ok), 3.0.0-RC1 (ok), 3.0.0-RC2 (not ok), 3.0.0 (not ok)

Comment: BAD_REQUEST is not 404, it's 400 status code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too after upgrading.

From my understanding, the security filter chain now runs on all dispatch types. Previously it didn't run on the error dispatcher. You can revert to the old behavior by calling:

`http.authorizeHttpRequests().shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)`

What causes re-filtering when dispatching an error to not make your request authenticated is the use of `OncePerRequestFilter`. Since you already executed the filter on the first dispatch, it will not run again when the error is dispatched. Another workaround is therefore to use a plain `Filter` instead.

---

Sources:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31852#issuecomment-1193695450
- [Spring security 6.0 AuthorizationFilter - questionable default for shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971183/spring-security-6-0-authorizationfilter-questionable-default-for-shouldfiltera)