# Spring security 6.0 AuthorizationFilter - questionable default for shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-security, authorization, spring-restcontroller

I spent a few hours today on a migration issue to Spring security 6.0 by replacing the deprecated `authorizeRequests()` method with `authorizeHttpRequests()`. I learned that under the hood, this implies replacing the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` with the new `AuthorizationFilter` in the security chain.
However, I got some unexpected results already for my unauthenticated register endpoint, that uses a JPA-validated `@Valid` request body and also answers with BadRequest = 400, if you try to register a user that already exists in the database.

When moving towards AuthorizationFilter, a *valid* register request still worked as expected, but the error cases (validation failure as well as already existing user) both replied with Unauthorized = 401, which is not acceptable for an unauthenticated endpoint...

I could solve this (eventually !) by chaining

```
.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
```

to `authorizeHttpRequests()`.

But now I started to wonder, if the new default behaviour makes sense...

The rather unspectacular code snippets are:

1. The controller mapped call, where the service can throw a `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` annotated `UserAlreadyExistsException`:

```
@PostMapping("/api/register")
public ResponseEntity<Void> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    service.registerUser(mapper.toEntity(userDto));
    return ok().build();
}
```

2. The relevant part of the SecurityFilterChain bean:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                               AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
    http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            //.authorizeRequests()  <-- deprecated, but working, using SecurityFilterInterceptor
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false) // without this line weird behavior since default is true
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/register").permitAll()
            // ... more requestMatchers and other stuff
}
```

So I digged deeper into the AuthorizationFilter - and there already the Javadoc is contradictory, if you look at the following snippet from `AuthorizationFilter` of spring security 6.0.1. The default of the first, new method contradicts the 3 method defaults below:

```
/**
 * Sets whether to filter all dispatcher types.
 * @param shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes should filter all dispatcher types. Default
 * is {@code true}
 * @since 5.7
 */
public void setShouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(boolean shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes) {
   this.observeOncePerRequest = !shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes;
   this.filterErrorDispatch = shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes;
   this.filterAsyncDispatch = shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes;
}
//...

/**
 * Sets whether this filter apply only once per request. By default, this is
 * <code>true</code>, meaning the filter will only execute once per request. Sometimes
 * users may wish it to execute more than once per request, such as when JSP forwards
 * are being used and filter security is desired on each included fragment of the HTTP
 * request.
 * @param observeOncePerRequest whether the filter should only be applied once per
 * request
 */
public void setObserveOncePerRequest(boolean observeOncePerRequest) {
   this.observeOncePerRequest = observeOncePerRequest;
}

/**
 * If set to true, the filter will be applied to error dispatcher. Defaults to false.
 * @param filterErrorDispatch whether the filter should be applied to error dispatcher
 */
public void setFilterErrorDispatch(boolean filterErrorDispatch) {
   this.filterErrorDispatch = filterErrorDispatch;
}

/**
 * If set to true, the filter will be applied to the async dispatcher. Defaults to
 * false.
 * @param filterAsyncDispatch whether the filter should be applied to async dispatch
 */
public void setFilterAsyncDispatch(boolean filterAsyncDispatch) {
   this.filterAsyncDispatch = filterAsyncDispatch;
}
```

Even worse, there seems to be a related vulnerability to bypass authorization as described in the link below, if you use the default. So I am wondering, if the default=true for `shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes` is making sense - or do I miss a point here?
https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-ORGSPRINGFRAMEWORKSECURITY-3092126

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best solution is disable filtering for `ASYNC`, `FORWARD` and `ERROR` dispatch types (which would be the default configuration in my opinion):

```java
http
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(true) // You can remove it because it is default configuration in Spring Security 6
        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
```

But my question is the same as yours. Does this default configuration make sense? Why would someone want to authenticate the error dispatch if the previous request was already authenticated. It will bring a lot of issues when people start migrating to Spring Boot 3 (Spring Security 6). And it is pretty hard to find out why this happens because it looks like as a redirect to an `/error` page. You see in your logs:

```
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Secured GET /basic
...
o.s.s.w.a.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl        : Responding with 403 status code
...
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Securing GET /error
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

It is somehow described in Spring Security documentation. But only for Spring Security 5.8 not for Spring Security 6.0.x (I know that you should migrate to Spring Security 5.8 before migrating to Spring Boot 3 but it is weird). And also the `ERROR` is not mentioned there only `FORWARD`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#switch-filter-all-dispatcher-types

I found another way how to resolve this issue if you use your custom Authentication Filter. You can enable filtering also for the `ERROR` dispatch type. But then authentication is processed twice and I do not see any good reason why to authenticate twice. You just need to override this method in your filter:

```java
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilterErrorDispatch() {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your confirming answer... Disabling filtering for ASYNC, FORWARD and ERROR dispatch type is exactly what I am using in this application. Problem is the unauthenticated register endpoint and my specs expicitly demanded 400 in case the user exists or missing params.

Meanwhile I have build other secured Spring applications on v6, where I use Oauth2 and there was no need to change the default - as only actuator endpoints are unauthenticated and don't care on error status..
However - as you confirmed - I still do not see any advantage of the current default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that answers your question but you are using AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry and you are looking at AuthorizationFilter. Check this link here:
[source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.java)

```
/**
     * Sets whether all dispatcher types should be filtered.
     * @param shouldFilter should filter all dispatcher types. Default is {@code true}
     * @return the {@link AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry} for further
     * customizations
     * @since 5.7
     */
    public AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(boolean shouldFilter) {
        this.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes = shouldFilter;
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
Yes, right. this Registry's class method is called by my securityFilterChain to change the AuthorizationFilter's default-value.
My question is, that I am wondering, why the default is "true" - and that I need to change it... (usually in Spring it works fine with default - I am a huge Spring fan:-))

Meanwhile - following the ref doc's advice I changed the line to:
`.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()`, but I need Dispatcher.ERROR in there to prevent my symptoms described...