# Configuration rules that worked in Spring Security 5.7.6 don't work in 6.0.1

Tags: spring-security

**Describe the bug**
Configuration rules that worked in Spring Security 5 don't work in 6.0.1.

After migrating the security configuration to Spring Security 6.0.1, if we use a bad credential then a browser is stuck and Hibernate runs a query endlessly and the control does not redirect to the login page. The project uses Spring MVC and ThymeLeaf.

To migrate from Spring Security 5 (Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE) to Spring Security 6.0.1 (Spring Boot 3.0.2) I changed `SecurityConfiguration.java` file from

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void  configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

to

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/h2-console/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                        .permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                        .permitAll())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

and I changed `SSUserDetailsService.java` file from

```java
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            User appUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

            if(appUser == null){
                System.out.println("User not found with the provided username" + appUser.toString());
                return null;
            }
            System.out.println("User from username " + appUser.toString());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    appUser.getUsername(),
                    appUser.getPassword(),
                    getAuthorities(appUser));

        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User appUser) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for(Role role: appUser.getRoles()){
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole());
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }
        System.out.println("User authorities are" + authorities.toString());
        return authorities;
    }
```

to

```java
   @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){
        try {
            User appUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

            if (appUser == null) {
                System.out.println("User not found with the provided username" + appUser.toString());
                return null;
            }
            System.out.println("User from username " + appUser.getUsername());
            return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                    .withUsername(appUser.getUsername())
                    .password(appUser.getPassword())
                    .roles(getAuthorities(appUser))
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

    private String[] getAuthorities(User appUser) {
        var authorities = new HashSet<String>();
        for (var role : appUser.getRoles()) {
            var grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole());
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority.getAuthority());
        }
        System.out.println("User authorities are " + authorities);
        return Arrays.copyOf(authorities.toArray(),authorities.size(), String[].class);
    }
```

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce error behavior (springboot_3.0 branch contains an example with Spring Security 6.0.1 (Spring Boot 3.0.2)):

1. git clone -b springboot_3.0 https://github.com/mhussainshah1/SpringBoot_404.git
2. cd SpringBoot_404
3. mvn clean package
4. mvn spring-boot:run
5. Open the browser with link http://localhost:8080/
6. Login with user/password (user is admin, password is password)

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.username from user_data u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.role from user_data_roles r1_0 join role r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
User from username admin
User authorities are [ADMIN]
```

8. Login with bad credential (user is dave, password is begreat)

The browser is stuck, and Hibernate query runs endlessly until stop by a
command `CTRL + C`

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.username from user_data u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.username from user_data u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.username from user_data u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.username from user_data u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
```

**Expected behavior**
After putting in bad credentials (username or password) the login page should appear with the following text
`Invalid username or password`

Steps to reproduce success behavior (master branch contains an example with Spring Security 5 (Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE)):

1. git clone https://github.com/mhussainshah1/SpringBoot_404.git
2. cd SpringBoot_404
3. mvn clean package
4. mvn spring-boot:run
5. Open browser with link http://localhost:8080/
6. Login page will open successfully
7. Log in with user/password (user is admin, password is password)
   The home page will open at the link  http://localhost:8080/
8. Login with bad credential (user is dave, password is begreat)
   It should redirect to Login Page and it

say `Invalid username or password`

[image: Login with Bad Credential]

**Sample**
A link to a GitHub repository with a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://github.com/mhussainshah1/SpringBoot_404.git). (see springboot_3.0 branch).

Comment: Where are your spring security debug logs?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is, that you get stuck in some `AuthorizationFilter` forwarding loop.

**To exclude this,** you can check if replacing `.authorizeHttpRequests()` by the (deprecated but still functionable) `.authorizeRequests()`shows the same issues (it uses `FilterSecurityInterceptor`under the hood instead of AuthorizationFilter). If it does - you can still try my hint adding "/login*" below, but if the issue is gone with the other method you can replace the deprecation as follows:

Replace back and add (chain) one of the following after the `.authorizeHttpRequests()`:

```java
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
```

or

```java
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
```

which is a little weaker...

I'd probably try also to **add `"/login*"`** as third string in your first `requestMatchers` permitting all call, as trying to authenticate for `login?...` when forwarding might (!) be the cause for getting into the loop.

I had a similar issue when migrating Spring security and the dispatching-directives to the autorization filter did the job for me - so I think it is no harm to have them in anyway.

You can cf here: [Spring security 6.0 AuthorizationFilter - questionable default for shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971183/spring-security-6-0-authorizationfilter-questionable-default-for-shouldfiltera)

Comment: I have tried all three ways separately but none of them resolve the issue. 1. replaced ```.authorizeHttpRequests()``` by the (deprecated) ```.authorizeRequests()``` . 2. adding ```.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)``` or ```.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()```  . 3. adding ```"/login*"``` as third string.

Answer (score 0):

I have change  the following method in `SecurityConfiguration.java` file from

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .and()
                .build();
}
```

to

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider userDetailsService(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(new SSUserDetailsService(appUserRepository));
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return provider;
}
```

Using `DaoAuthenticationProvider` has stopped the loop if authentication fails and works fine